# How to install a .INF file easily?

Tags: windows-7, windows, usb, drivers, android

I am trying to install the USB drivers for Android found here:  https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

The main file is: `android_winusb.inf`

I was trying this but it doesn't work. It tells me installation failed.

```
RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 path-to\android_winusb.inf
```

I tried right clicking the file and clicking install, but I get "The INF file you selected does not support this method of installation".

I want the easiest way to install without going to Manage Devices. Ideally a click or a command or a batch file that I would run. Please help

Answer (score -1):

Open elevated command prompt and type in the following:

```
Rundll32 syssetup,SetupInfObjectInstallAction DefaultInstall 128 .\android_winusb.inf
```

Or:

```
InstallHinfSection(NULL,NULL,TEXT("DefaultInstall 132 path-to-inf\android_winusb.inf"),0);
```

Comment: That produces an installation failed error.

Comment: Have you tried to manually update the driver and provide the INF file from device manager ?

Comment: Device Managers works, but I do not want to do this for 20+ computers.

Comment: Again are you using elevated command prompt ?

Comment: Try this command : pnputil -i -a *.inf﻿

Comment: As elevated user I don't get the error but the device driver is still not installed for my device.

Comment: Or if the above didn't work this should work  :  rundll32.exe advpack.dll,LaunchINFSectionEx myinf.inf,,c:\temp\mydata.cab,36

Comment: That last command ran but it didn't do anything.

Comment: The last comment adds the INF file to the driver cache now try to re run the commands above and check if it installs or try uninstalling the device and reboot

Comment: I just did. I even uninstalled and rebooted and still it does not work.

Comment: To the downvoters : this answer is correct in actual scenario but in @J_Strauton situation is different